# $(...).tooltip is not a function using bootstrap 4 in npm webpack

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, npm, twitter-bootstrap-tooltip

I can't seem to get [tooltips](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/components/tooltips/) working in [bootstrap 4](https://getbootstrap.com/) using npm webpack.

I've just installed these node vendors...

```
$ npm install jquery
$ npm install bootstrap
$ npm install popper.js --save
```

And I am requiring vendors like so...

```
global.jQuery = require('jquery/dist/jquery.min.js');

require('bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js');
require('popper.js/dist/popper.min.js');
```

I've tried both the `dist` and `src` for bootstrap and popper.js.

I am calling the [tooltips](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/components/tooltips/) function like this after the required vendors.

```
(function ($) {

    // enable tooltips for everything
    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();

})(jQuery);
```

And I am always getting this error...

[image]

Other bootstrap javascript functions work like [modals](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/components/modal/) etc.

If you want to test my exact setup, [download a test project here](http://dev.joshmoto.wtf/tooltip.zip) and just run `npm install` and then `npm run production` and see the `index.html` for error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Either import required plugins separately, or load all:

```
require('bootstrap');
```

Everything is well explained in the [official documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/webpack/).

Also many plugins depend on the `$` symbol, so it's good to alias this one too:

```
global.jQuery = global.$ = require('jquery');
```

Comment: That is so strange i was using `require('bootstrap');` from the start and only tried absolute paths for debugging. Thanks this now works. And cheers for the jquery alias trick.

Comment: Every npm package has so called “main script” so you usually just import by its name.

Comment: global.jQuery did the trick, after countless attempts. I don't understand why this is required since webpack has .autoProvidejQuery()... but nevertheless, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I wasted entire day on this, trying to load bootstrap `v4-alpha.5` with all kinds of Webpack plugins to no avail.
It turns out, after I switched to `preset-env` bootstrap started "bringing in" its own version of jQuery `v3.6` (actually Webpack, by reading boostrap's dependencies), which was different than what I had in `package.json`, so consequently only that jQuery got amended with bootstrap's plugins (`util`, `alert`, `button`, `carousel`, `tooltip`, `popover`, ...).

The solution was to make sure that bootstrap's jQuery resolves to the version I'm using, which was accomplished by adding this entry to `package.json`:

```
  "resolutions": {
    "bootstrap/jquery": "2.2.4"
  }
```

This is currently only honoured by `yarn`.
A similar feature for `npm` is tracked [here](https://github.com/npm/statusboard/issues/343).